# Emulating Escrow with Stripe (Delayed Payment Confirmation) (and Stripe Connect)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, stripe-payments

I'm creating a teacher-student platform in which any student can request a lesson from a teacher. In it, teachers can choose to accept or refuse a request. So, I have (at least) 2 options as to how to go about this, I guess:

1. Accept the payment upon request, and then, if the request is refused, the amount goes back to the student, as in-platform credits.
2. Register only the payment method upon request, and then later confirm the payment only after the teacher accepts the request.

I'm currently choosing option 2, because I think option 1, though more ideal, would complicate things, since then both teachers and students would need to have Stripe Connect accounts, as far as I understand (maybe this doesn't complicate things, but it at least creates friction because they would both need to be onboarded on Stripe Connect).

Anyways, my question is about how to achieve this with any of those options, or maybe another, easier one.

---

Here's a breakdown of what I have in mind for option 2:

1. Create payment intent (backend).
2. The user fills the (React) form.
3. The payment method is submitted to the backend, and linked to the payment intent.

   - How would I achieve this? I'm thinking about adding the payment intent ID to the payment method's metadata. But is there a method for just updating the payment intent on the frontend with a payment method, such as `@stripe/stripe-js`'s `stripe.confirmPayment()`?
4. Later, upon the teacher's acceptance, we find the respective payment method and payment intent, and confirm the payment to the teacher's Stripe Connect account (backend).

I'm using Next.js with React Server Components/Actions. What I have so far is very simlar to [what's on the Stripe Docs](https://docs.stripe.com/stripe-js/react):

The frontend:

```
"use client"

import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js"
import {
  Elements,
  PaymentElement,
  useElements,
  useStripe,
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js"

import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

import {
  Box,
  CircularProgress,
  Typography,
} from "@mui/material"

import { createPaymentIntent } from "@actions"

import { LoadingState } from "@context"

enum LoadingState {
  Loading,
  Loaded,
}

const stripePromise = loadStripe(
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY!
)

export default function Payment() {
  const [loadingState, setLoadingState] =
    useState<LoadingState>(LoadingState.Loading)

  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] =
    useState<string>("")

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getPaymentIntent() {
      setLoadingState(LoadingState.Loading)

      const secret = await createPaymentIntent()
      if (secret) setClientSecret(secret)

      setLoadingState(LoadingState.Loaded)
    }

    getPaymentIntent()
  }, [])

  if (loadingState === LoadingState.Loading) {
    return <CircularProgress />
  }

  return (
    <Box p={3}>
      <Typography>Payment</Typography>

      <Elements
        stripe={stripePromise}
        options={{
          clientSecret,
        }}
      >
        <CheckoutForm />
      </Elements>
    </Box>
  )
}

function CheckoutForm() {
  const stripe = useStripe()
  const elements = useElements()

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    if (!stripe || !elements) return

    try {
      // How do I link this to the specific payment intent?
      // Is there a way of doing it from the frontend?
      // If not, why can we confirm payment from the frontend but not update the payment method of a payment intent?
      const result = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
        elements,
        metadata: {
          customer_username: "psygo", // Just an example
        },
      })
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)    
    }
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <PaymentElement />
      <button disabled={!stripe}>Submit</button>
    </form>
  )    
}
```

The backend:

```
"use server"

import { PaymentMethodResult } from "@stripe/stripe-js"
import Stripe from "stripe"

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY!)

export async function createPaymentIntent() {
  try {
    const paymentIntent =
      await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: 1099,
        currency: "usd",
      })

    stripe.paymentMethods.list()

    return paymentIntent.client_secret
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}

export async function updatePaymentIntentWithPaymentMethod(
  paymentIntentId: string,
  paymentMethodId: string
) {
  try {
    const newPaymentIntent =
      await stripe.paymentIntents.update(paymentIntentId, {
        payment_method: paymentMethodId,
      })
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}

export async function confirmPaymentAfterTeacherAcceptance(
  paymentIntentId: string
) {
  try {
    const confirmedPaymentIntent =
      await stripe.paymentIntents.confirm(paymentIntentId)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}
```

I'll update the code as I improve upon it.

Comment: I think some of the assumptions here are misaligned. 1/ The end customer, the students in this case do not need to have a Stripe account, the teachers do as you would be making payouts to them, https://stripe.com/connect. 2/ Accepting the payment, then refunding them would be costly to your business. 3/ If the teacher can accept the request within 7 days, you might be able to use https://docs.stripe.com/payments/place-a-hold-on-a-payment-method. There are some limitation there. 4/ Your business use case more sounds like https://docs.stripe.com/payments/save-and-reuse where you collect PM first

Comment: 1. If the teachers refuses the request, in option 1, then I would put the money back into the user's in-platform wallet, which I think would be clunky or not possible to do without Stripe Connect. 2. Both of the options I enumerated are so I avoid having to issue refunds, which are indeed costly. 3 and 4. Thanks, I din't know about either.